# Python logger output not matching logger and handler level

Tags: python, python-logging

I have created a custom Python Logger with a StreamHandler, initially set to `logging.INFO` level. This correctly hides `DEBUG` level logs and outputs `INFO` level logs.

I also created a function that changes the level of both the logger and handler to `logging.DEBUG`. Printing out `logger.getEffectiveLevel()` and `handler.level` both show that it is indeed changed.

However, I am still only getting `INFO` level logs when I expect `DEBUG` level logs to also show up. What am I missing? Looked through a bunch of posts with similar issues, but all of them are attempting to log with the root logger and are missing or not configuring their handler, which is not the case here.

Python version 3.8.6.

Code is split into two parts:

1. The main execution:

```
logger = get_logger("my_logger") // Creates custom Python logger

async def main():
    <...Other code...>

    logger.debug("Before update")
    logger.info("Before update")
    print(f"{logger.name} - {logger.getEffectiveLevel()}")
    for handler in logger.handlers:
        print(f"{type(handler)} - {handler.level}")

    <...Code that updates level for get_level() function...>

    update_log_levels() // Function that changes logging level

    print(f"{logger.name} - {logger.getEffectiveLevel()}")
    for handler in logger.handlers:
        print(f"{type(handler)} - {handler.level}")

    logger.debug("After update")
    logger.info("After update")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

2. Custom logger

```
class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name: str, level: int):
        super().__init__(name, level)

        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setLevel(level)
        handler.setFormatter(FORMATTER)
        self.addHandler(handler)

loggers = {}

def get_logger(name: str):
    level = get_level() // Function that gets level
    if name not in loggers.keys():
        loggers[name] = CustomLogger(name, level)

    return loggers[name]

def update_log_levels():
    for _, logger in loggers.items():
        level = get_level() // Function that gets level
        logger.setLevel(level)
        for handler in logger.handlers:
            handler.setLevel(level)
```

Output I get:

```
2022-11-04 15:06:40,102 - my_logger - INFO     - Before update
my_logger - 20
<class 'logging.StreamHandler'> - 20
my_logger - 10
<class 'logging.StreamHandler'> - 10
2022-11-04 15:06:40,102 - my_logger - INFO     - After update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the standard `logging` module is not designed for that pattern. A `Logger` instance should be created by the `logging.getLogger()`.(See [the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects). It says 'NEVER'.)

Use the `logging.setLoggerClass()` to register your `CustomLogger` and call the `logging.getLogger()`.

And you can manipulate existing loggers you created like this.

```
logger_names = set()

def get_logger(name):
    logger_names.add(name)
    return logging.getLogger(name)

def update_log_levels():
    for name in logger_names:
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        ...
```